# How to redirect incoming traffic in apache depending on the loadbalaner in between?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, http-redirect, elastic-load-balancer

I have an apache instance running in AWS ec2(this is a Directconnect AWS account) . Two application loadbalancers (internal and internet facing have been set up. Now I need the traffic that is coming in from outside organizations network, i.e the traffic coming in through the internet facing load balancer to be redirected to www.mysite.com/location.php with the inside network(internal loadbalancer)
 traffic going to www.mysite.com.

currently, apache is listening on ports 80 and 443 automatically redirecting HTTP to HTTPS traffic using "RewriteEngine on"

Answer (score 0):

At the moment ALBs and ELBs can't handle URL redirection on their own.

One option is to put AWS CloudFront infront of your public loadbalancer doing the redirection.

Another possible option(Not tested before) to use the trace identifier in [X-Amzn-Trace-Id](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html) header appended by the Load Balancer, to decide the redirect, writing a redirect rule in EC2 webserver.

Comment: Thank you Ashan. I have read in blogs about the X-Amzn-Trace-Id .Is there a way to know the X-Amzn-Trace-Id for a particular ALB ?